# jQuery setInterval not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, setinterval

I have a function that I want to loop. I found the easiest way to do this was using setInterval. When I tried this the function only runs once. Please advise where I am going wrong. Cheers

```
function empMove() { $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', '-100px')};

setInterval(empMove, 2000);
```

I have a div with multiple rows and I want to show only one at a time, hence I am decreasing the margin-top each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current code sets the top margin to -100px. Try

`function empMove() { $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', '`**`-=100`**`')};`

Comment: Thanks that works great. Can you just clarify that my code was looping but it was constantly setting margin-top to the same value?

Comment: @ClintonGreen [jQ docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2). `.css( propertyName, value )` **sets** the specified CSS property **to** the value. So, if you use `.css('margin-top', '-100px')`, it **sets** top margin **to** exactly -100px. The second and later calls to `empMove()` does not change the top margin. The div is not moving as its top margin stays at -100px. `.css('margin-top', '-=100')`, on the other hand, **decrements** the current top margin by 100px.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the **jQuery timing plugin (2KB)** ([GitHub Repository](https://github.com/creativecouple/jquery-timing), [Docs](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/)).

It  provides easy-to-use loop animations and much more. Have a look:

```
function empMove() { 

    $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', '-=100px').repeat().wait(2000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check out the plugin. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayOnly() {
    var initHeight = $('.wrapper').height();
    $('.wrapper').height(initHeight);
    $('p').not('.read').fadeOut(2000, function () {
        if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
            $('.wrapper').animate({
                height: $('.inner').height()
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}

$("button").click(displayOnly);
```

In action [on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/7gW5w/4/)